# Powershell and XAML checkboxes problem while executing

Tags: powershell, xaml, checkbox

I made a XAML form from visual studio 2012, the XAML form have checkboxes that you select to get the information.

Every checkbox have a powershell function behind.

When executing the form, if I select one checkbox and unselect it, when I press the button to execute the function, even if the checkbox is unchecked at the moment I press the execution button its continuing thinking that the checkbox is selected. But I unchecked the checkbox before clicking the execution button. So it's continuing executing other functions that I don't want it to execute.

Do we have a kind of code that force PowerShell to think the checkbox is $false while the form is in execution ?

Here an example of code:

```
 $apps_checkbox = $Window.FindName("apps_checkbox")
    $apps_checkbox.Add_Click({ 
    if($apps_checkbox.isChecked -eq $true){
       $retrievebutton.add_click({
       IF(!(GCI ".\$FOLDERNAME\$COMP" | WHERE-OBJECT NAME -EQ "APPS")){ 
        NEW-ITEM -ITEMTYPE DIRECTORY -NAME APPS -PATH ".\$FOLDERNAME\$COMP" 
       }
       NEW-ITEM -ITEMTYPE FILE -PATH 
       ".\$FOLDERNAME\$COMP\APPS\APPS-$COMP.TXT" 
       LIST-APPS 
        }) 
       } 
      })
```

Comment: Please [edit the code into your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69376475/edit), then it's easier to format correctly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still trying to figure out what you are trying to do, because we can't see the rest of your code, but from your latest comment, I gather you are defining the function in the wrong event handler.

Instead of `$apps_checkbox.Add_Click({..})`, you need to check if that checkbox is checked or not **inside** the click event of the `$retrievebutton`:

```
$retrievebutton = $Window.FindName("retrievebutton")
$retrievebutton.Add_Click({ 
    $apps_checkbox = $Window.FindName("apps_checkbox")
    if($apps_checkbox.IsChecked){
        # No need to test using -Force. Also throw away the diretoryInfo object it returns
        # You may need to use 'Script-scoping' here on the variables $FOLDERNAME and $COMP
        # like $script:FOLDERNAME and $script:COMP
        $null = New-Item -Path ".\$FOLDERNAME\$COMP\APPS" -ItemType Directory -Force
        $null = New-Item -Path ".\$FOLDERNAME\$COMP\APPS\APPS-$COMP.TXT" -ItemType File -Force
        # call your function 
        LIST-APPS 
    }
})
```

Another option would be to disable the `$retrievebutton` button the moment the checkbox gets unchecked. That way you don't need to test if the checkbox is checked or not, because the user can't click the button if it is unchecked.

Comment: I only know that the "if" is doing the job to know if its checked. Naturally where not checked if not checked. Ill try your code. Thank you for your help

Comment: I try your code and it is not working.

Comment: @Kerberos5938 Great, explain what _not working_ means

Comment: When the form is in execution, when I select and unselect the same checkbox, when I press retrieve execution button, its trying to execute this checkbox even its unchecked. just because I checked it once.

Comment: @Kerberos5938 Please see my edited answer

Comment: Your solution is working Theo, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Theo is right: the code below resolve the problem:

```
$retrievebutton = $Window.FindName("retrievebutton")
$retrievebutton.Add_Click({ 
    $apps_checkbox = $Window.FindName("apps_checkbox")
    if($apps_checkbox.IsChecked){
        # No need to test using -Force. Also throw away the diretoryInfo object it returns
        # You may need to use 'Script-scoping' here on the variables $FOLDERNAME and $COMP
        # like $script:FOLDERNAME and $script:COMP
        $null = New-Item -Path ".\$FOLDERNAME\$COMP\APPS" -ItemType Directory -Force
        $null = New-Item -Path ".\$FOLDERNAME\$COMP\APPS\APPS-$COMP.TXT" -ItemType File -Force
        # call your function 
        LIST-APPS 
    }
})
```

thank you